# how can i make spark streaming to start from the offset which is not processed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I am working on a steaming application POC where I get the message from a kafka producer and in spark structured steaming consumer I get those topic and store it in delta table .I am maintaining a checkpoint dir in S3 using the `option("checkpointLocation", checkPointdir)` .
My query is how can i read this location to get the latest offset  which is processed in case my stream failed and pass to   starting offset   **.option("startingOffsets", readvalue)**

I went through below reference but without much clue how to read the value from s3 or I have to write a separate scala program to read that from S3.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html
My offset file look like below

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":1594923737216,"conf":{"spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass":"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider","spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy":"min","spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
{"json-topic":{"0":41}}
```

Any clue on this would be helpful

Comment: Spark automically read the data from that checkpointLocation

Comment: @Srinivas Does it mean I have to remove .option("startingOffsets", "eraliest") option .

Comment: first priority it will check config in checkpoint location, if nothing found in that location then ```.option("startingOffsets", "eraliest")``` will apply.

Comment: Ohk thanks for the reply let me see what’s wrong here